# Is locking on the requested object a bad idea?

Tags: .net, thread-safety

Most advice on thread safety involves some variation of the following pattern:

```
public class Thing
{
    private readonly object padlock = new object();

    private IDictionary stuff, andNonsense;

    public Thing()
    {
        this.stuff = new Dictionary();
        this.andNonsense = new Dictionary();
    }

    public IDictionary Stuff
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this.padlock)
            {
                if (this.stuff.Count == 0)
                    this.stuff = this.SomeExpensiveOperation();
                return this.stuff;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public IDictionary AndNonsense
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this.padlock)
            {
                if (this.andNonsense.Count == 0)
                    this.andNonsense = this.AnotherExpensiveOperation();
                return this.andNonsense;
            }
        }
    }
    // Rest of class...
}
```

In cases where the get operations are expensive and unrelated, a single locking object is unsuitable because a call to `Stuff` would block all calls to `AndNonsense`, degrading performance. And rather than create a lock object for each call, wouldn't it be better to acquire the lock on the member itself (assuming it is not something that implements `SyncRoot` or somesuch for that purpose? For example:

```
public IDictionary Stuff
{
    get
    {
        lock (this.stuff)
        {
            if (this.stuff.Count == 0)
                this.stuff = this.SomeExpensiveOperation();
            return this.stuff;
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely, I have never seen this approach recommended or warned against. Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT 24 May 2010**

> I have made some extensive changes because I really borked my example. Serves me right for trying to simplify the example too much for clarity.
>
> Summary of edits:
>
> - Locking object in first example is no longer static (my original example was from a static class).
> - Fields/properties no longer a string, and initialised in constructor so never null.
> - Moved return statement inside the `lock{...}` block.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230716/difference-between-locklocker-and-lockvariable-which-i-am-using

Comment: You should also fix the fact that you're accessing the variables outside the locks - the return statements should be inside the lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, I would use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` which allows you to have multiple overlapping 'Read' locks by only completely locking when you enter a 'Write' lock either directly or via an upgrade lock. Alternatively, you can go lock-free by using `Thread.MemoryBarrier`, but this is tricky and as an advanced technique will require some specialized tests to make sure it actually works.

Comment: This actually looks like a very good idea. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Your version of the "standard advice" would be very bad - it would use a single lock for the whole AppDomain. Normally the lock object is an *instance* variable, not a static one.

Now, as for your suggestion: even worse idea, IMO - because you don't know what else will be locking on it. Some other code may be using the same string - and likewise locking on it. Now suppose two threads acquire *two* locks instead of one. When you've no idea what's locking on what, you have no hope of avoiding deadlock other than dumb luck. (There's also the nullity issue mentioned by codeka.)

Additionally, this starts to be confusing if the value of the variable changes - you would then potentially have two threads executing inside the lock block at the same time, which presumably you were trying to avoid.

Wherever possible, you should (IMO) lock on something that only your code knows about. While that in itself won't keep you deadlock free or safe, it's a good starting point as it makes it much easier to reason about your code. There's nothing to say that has to be a single lock per instance - you can create finer-grained locks if you want - but keep them private to yourself if at all possible.

Comment: I have fixed the mistakes in the example that have already been pointed out, but have just realised that other code could take out a lock on those fields via the public properties, rendering it rather useless it would seem. (My home laptop does not have VS installed so I can't test this theory right now.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I assume you haven't actually tried this because `lock(null)` will throw an `ArgumentNullException`, so you can't actually do it like that.

You could use a separate "stuffLock" object, like so:

```
class Thing
{
    private string stuff;
    private object stuffLock = new Object();

    public string Stuff
    {
        get
        {
            lock(stuffLock)
            {
                if (stuff == null)
                    stuff = "Still threadsafe";
            }
            return stuff;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "return stuff;" should be within the lock{} block.

Comment: It was the use of a dedicated locking object for every member requiring thread safety that I was trying to avoid in the first place, but it seems that isn't really possible to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, be aware that your examples are **not** intrinsically thread safe, as you are querying the value of the variable you are trying to protect from *outside* the lock.

Another thread can get a slice, just after the first thread running Stuff {get;} releases the lock, and sets the value of this.stuff to null again before the first thread actually returns this.stuff

Comment: Interesting point. So (ignoring the other problems in the example I used) the return statement should be within the lock block?

Comment: In the example above, you're OK as you are as there are no other assignments to this.stuff. If you assign it anywhere else, even within lock(padlock) {...}, then your example could break. I'd rather not leave this potential pitfall behind, and would put the return within the lock anyway.

Bear in mind that once the value of this.stuff is returned to the caller, the caller can do anything with the object (e.g. .Clear() or .Add() ) and those operations will not be constrained by any locks invoked within your Thing class.

Answer (score 0):

As well the problem that [@codeka points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895249/is-locking-on-the-requested-object-a-bad-idea/2895270#2895270), note also that `lock()` requires a *reference* type, so your proposed system would have to come up with a different approach for value types.

Answer (score 0):

Never lock on types or strings, or other objects that may potentially be shared accorss multiple appdomains. Locking on a an instance field as such is no problem, just ensure that your instance has exclusive access to it.